# meta tags with c# code content don't render

Tags: c#, webforms, meta-tags, meta

For example- this is my meta tag:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<%=eSeo.keyWords%>" />
```

It suppose to become-

```
<meta name="keywords" content="food,dogs,cats" />
```

and I can see through the page source in the browser that it stays:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<%=eSeo.keyWords%>" />
```

As a string..

I tried to update the meta tag from the behind code, and it doesn't work as well:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            HtmlHead pHtml = Page.Header;

            foreach (HtmlMeta metaTag in pHtml.Controls.OfType<HtmlMeta>())
            {
                if (metaTag.Name.Equals("keywords", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    metaTag.Content = eSeo.keyWords;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is give the meta tag an ID and runat="server" and use binding to set the value.

For example:

```
<meta ID="MetaKeywords" runat="server" name="keywords" content="<%#eSeo.keyWords%>" />
```

and in code behind

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MetaKeywords.DataBind();
```

....

Comment: Its not woking.. That's what I get:  <meta id="ctl00_Meta_keywords" content="<%=eSeo.keyWords%>" name="keywords">  I gave the id "Meta_keywords"

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: The tag needs the attribute runat="server" and the content should use data bind not response.write

Comment: <%#eSeo.keyWords%> not "<%=eSeo.keyWords%>

Comment: I put the attribute runat="server" and changed the content to data bind, still not working :/

Comment: Are you calling MetaKeywords.DataBind(); in the code behind on Page_Init as sample above?

Comment: Its working! I had to move the init of some params to the Page_Init from the Page_Load)  Thanx!!